# Compilation error ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext in MacOSX

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, theano

1. I'm trying to replicate a tutorial example in the [pyLearn2](http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/) documentation. When I run `python make_dataset.py`, in the example, I got this error:

   ```
   11:17 $ python make_dataset.py

   /Users/user/pylearn2/pylearn2/utils/image.py:16: UserWarning: Unable to import matplotlib. Some features unavailable. Original exception: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/_macosx.so, 2): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
   ```

   Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO

   Expected in: `/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib`

   I can import `matplotlib` and image in python in command line. Could someone help me understand what it is complaining about and how to fix the error?
2. Another problem (which may or may not be related to the problem above) is a linking error

   Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:

   ```
   g++ -dynamiclib -g -O3 -fno-math-errno -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-write-strings -march=core-avx-i -mmmx -mno-3dnow -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -mno-sse4a -mcx16 -msahf -mno-movbe -maes -mpclmul -mpopcnt -mno-abm -mno-lwp -mno-fma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mno-bmi -mno-bmi2 -mno-tbm -mavx -mno-avx2 -msse4.2 -msse4.1 -mno-lzcnt -mno-rtm -mno-hle -mrdrnd -mf16c -mfsgsbase -mno-rdseed -mno-prfchw -mno-adx -mfxsr -mxsave -mxsaveopt -mno-avx512f -mno-avx512er -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512pf --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=6144 -mtune=core-avx-i -D NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -fPIC -undefined dynamic_lookup -I/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -o /Users/user/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-13.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.5-64/tmpBdy9w9/49d70155ef39a124cbfa83c600416644.so /Users/user/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-13.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.5-64/tmpBdy9w9/mod.cpp -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib

   ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.5

   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

   Exception: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}(mean), '\n', 'Compilation failed (return status=1): ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.5. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status. ', '[InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}(mean)]')
   ```

   I am running `pyLearn2` on Mac OSX Mavericks. I am not sure how to fix the error: the library seems to be in my system in several places:

   ```
   /usr/local/Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.7.3/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib
   /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib
   /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.7.3/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib
   ```

   I am not sure which one to link and how I should link.

   I have changed (added) the paths to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` which didn't fix the problem.

   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [one possible solution](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2010-November/022662.html) is to manually create a link to the .dylib file:

> sudo ln -sf
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
>   /opt/local/lib/libGL.dylib
>
> sudo ln -sf
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
>   /opt/local/lib/libpng.dylib
>
> sudo ln -sf
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
>   /opt/local/lib/libtiff.dylib
>
> sudo ln -sf
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
>   /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib
>
> Why does this work? Because for whatever reason, when Apple requests
>   libJPEG.dyld, whatever system searches for it finds
>   /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.dyld because the search is case insensitive.
>   For a Unix operating system. Go figure. The lines above will force any
>   program looking for libjpeg.dyld to be redirected to Apple's
>   libJPEG.dyld.

Another user suggested [setting DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.apple.macports.user/22154):

> You could also use DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH. I had to use that to
>   avoid Apple's libJPEG getting in the way of apps that expected the
>   libjpeg port. See the man page for dlopen() for details.